# How to construct an example of i.i.d. sequence in a probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P) \to \mathbb R$ be a random variable. I usually encounter a statement "let $(X_n)_n$ be an i.i.d. sample of $X$". However, I could not imagine how such sequence appears in a specific probability space.

Could you please construct such a sequence from $X$?

Comment: This is highly non-trivial to prove and not even possible on every probability space.

Comment: Usually, it means that one constructs a product space from copies of $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and defines $X_n(\omega)=X(\omega_n)$. ($\omega$ is a sequence here , i.e., $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots)$.)

Comment: This is handled by the Kolmogorov extension theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem

Comment: So this is generally impossible without extending the probability space.  Consider $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ and $P[\{0\}]=P[\{1\}]=1/2$.  We cannot produce a sequence of i.i.d. $Bern(1/2)$ random variables on this space.